# Poisson Process Probability Proof from Simulation

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I am trying to create a computer program to simulate a Poisson process.

Problem : A business man parks illegally for 2 hours each day (1 hour * 2 occurrence), given that rate of police patrol $\lambda = 0.6$ patrols/hour.

How do I calculate the probability, from the sample as in (given)/(total), that if I increase the number of days sample, i will find the probability of the businessman being fined as :

$1-e^{-\lambda \tau } = 1-e^{-0.6*2}$

Sample:
[Sample for 8 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9iH5.png)

Comment: You already have the mathematical probability.  To simulate, you want $k$ instances of iid random variables $X_1, ..., X_k$ that are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda=0.6$, and then define $Y_i = 1\{X_i\leq 2\}$ (so $Y_i=1$ if we get a ticket and zero else).  So $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i = 1 - e^{-1.2}$ (wp1).  Alternatively you could define $N_i$ as iid with Poisson distribution and then define $Y_i = 1\{N_i\geq 1\}$.

Comment: Is it possible to get the probability by (# of fines)/(# of parking)? Off course, i checked and its incorrect. But what's the logic behind the probability given a practical sample?

Comment: Since $Y_i = 1$ if we get a fine on day $i$, and 0 else, then indeed $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i$ is (number fines)/(number days).  I am assuming we cannot be fined twice on teh same day.

Comment: What is the implication of tao = 2 then? What if its possible to be fined twice on the same day? Do we treat it as different instances due to it being independent and memoryless?

Comment: $e^{-\lambda \tau} = P[X>\tau]$ is the probability that no officer comes during the $\tau$-hour time we spend illegally parking (recall that $X$ is defined as exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda = .6$).  You can imagine a simulation of $k$ back-to-back frames, each frame consisting of the 2-hour time we spent parking.  This observes that we do not care about the other times we are not parking.  You could simulate the Poisson process over each 2-hour frame, but it is enough to simulate the first arrival after the start of the frame to know if we get a fine or not on that frame.

Comment: That kind of make sense, thank you